# Use 12 different date ranges in join statement-SQL without re-running the join 12 times

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Supposedly I have 2 tables in the formats below:

Table 1: Visits

```
Customer | Website_visit_id  | Time_of_visit
```

Table 2: Booking

```
Customer | Hotel_booking_id  | Time_of_booking
```

I created a table that has customer's id, their booking, and all the visits they made to the website within 30 days prior to making the booking using this:

```
select customer, booking_id, website_visit_id
from visits a 
  join booking b 
    on a.customer = b.customer
   and Time_of_visit between dateadd(days, -30, time_of_booking) and time_of_booking
```

My question is- if I want to expand this time frame to look at how many visits within 60,90,120...365 days prior to making the booking, how do I do that most efficiently (instead of having to run the join 12 times with the dateadd number changed? Is there a way to add a parameter in place of the '30' days in the join statement?

The output can be in the form of a list of booking and their corresponding visits/ timeframe, or a table of bookings and total of visits for each time frame (something that looks like this:

```
Time_frame| Customer | Hotel_booking_id | Number of visits
T30D      | Mike     | 1A               | 5
T60D      | Mike     | 1A               | 15
T90D      | Mike     | 1A               | 22
T120D     | Mike     | 1A               | 27

Thank you in advance
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, sql-server, oracle...? Providing sample data and desired results would also improve the quality of your question and increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to dynamically build a query, you should look to see if your DB supports dynamic queries/sql. Essentially, instead of running a query, you would run a stored procedure with logic to identify what your query parameters should be. From there, you would be able to dynamically create your query based on your preferred logic and execute it.

I'm not sure which DB you are using however I know that MySQL and Oracle DBs support this.

Please see links below for further information:

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm)
[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)